# ListView : Arraylist.insert() not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, arraylist

I'm working on a note-taking app. I'm using a listview to display the notes from my sqlite database. Because I want the latest notes first, I flip the arraylist that stores the notes(using collections.reverse(arraylist)) and add it to my listadapter. When I write a new note however, I want to insert this new note to the first element of my arraylist using something like arraylist.insert(0, notes). I then call my arrayadapter.notifyDataSetChanged. It doesn't work. However my last element in the listview repeats itself once I do this insert. If I insert twice, it repeats itself twice. If I use arraylist.add(notes). This works.
Please help. The code for inserting the notes is below.

```
            sqlHandler.addNotes(notes_);
            notesListData.insert(notes_, 0); //notesListData is the arraylist   storing the notes
            //notesListData.add(notes_) - This works except it makes the notes the last element of the listview
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Can you show us a short sample of code which reproduces the problem. Perhaps you need to invalidate the whole (so it is all redrawn)

Comment: I think again you have get from db otherwise it will override first item which came previously,call again from db or just remove all the elements from list  and add the first latest item and after that db list to the list then your latest item will come first

Comment: @Allu, I've called from the DB while working with the app. NotifyDataSetChanged would not work except I use .add(), .insert(), or .clear().  That's what you're saying right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree x-code's comment.

> I won't vote you down but that's not a good answer because it does not take advantage of view recycling. – x-code

So, If I make code, I change this for using view recycling.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.individual_notelist, parent, false);            
        convertView = view;
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notes_);
        String note_ = notes.get(position).getNote();
        if (note_.length() < 40){
            textView.setText(note_);
        }
        else {
            textView.setText(note_.substring(0, Math.min(note_.length(), 40)) + " ...");
        }
     return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. I was implementing convertView the wrong way in my adapter. I did something like this

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.individual_notelist, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notes_);
            String note_ = notes.get(position).getNote();
            if (note_.length() < 40){
                textView.setText(note_);
            }
            else {
                textView.setText(note_.substring(0, Math.min(note_.length(), 40)) + " ...");
            }
            return view;
        }
        else
        {
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

I simply made my getView this :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.individual_notelist, parent, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notes_);
            String note_ = notes.get(position).getNote();
            if (note_.length() < 40){
                textView.setText(note_);
            }
            else {
                textView.setText(note_.substring(0, Math.min(note_.length(), 40)) + " ...");
            }
            return view;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I won't vote you down but that's not a good answer because it does not take advantage of view recycling.

Comment: Thanks @x-code. I corrected my app code on android studio this morning.